# Choice of policy class template parameter based on overloaded constructor

Tags: c++, templates, policy, crtp

I would like a template class to automatically pick it's parameter based on the type of class passed to the constructor.
objects already have types.

```
InputA a;
InputA a2;
InputB b;
```

these types should be understood by constructors

```
out<>(a) out;
```

is

```
out<InputA>(a) out;
```

.

```
out<>(a2) out;
```

is

```
out<InputA>(a2) out;
```

.

```
out<>(b) out;
```

is

```
out<InputB>(b) out;
```

it seems redundant to define the template argument (the policy) when this can be extracted from the type of the input parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the same problem that happend with [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).
The standard workaround for this problem is to define a template factory (like [`std::make_pair()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair)).

e.g.

```
template<class policy>
out<policy> make_out(policy p)
{
    return out<policy>(p);
}

auto o = make_out(a);
```

Comment: this is good. but just too make sure, is there a way to do this with a class instead of a function? something like CRTP may be?

Comment: I am not aware of anything like this.